# AngularJS slider range value is not displaying on it?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, slider

I am trying to implement AngularJS slider bar from Google search, I can bale to filter it out based on my slider selection, but I am unable to display the it's minimum and maximum range values at the starting and ending of the slider bar(on top or at starting/ending places of slider bar).

Like sample:

[image]

If I give like: `<slider floor="0" ceiling="50" ng-model-low="lower_price_bound" ng-model-high="upper_price_bound"></slider>`, then my slider is filtering fine(of course it won't show any range values on top of slider bar)

But If I give like: `<slider floor="0" ceiling="50" ng-model-low="lower_price_bound" ng-model-high="upper_price_bound" ng-model="itemrange.maxvalue"></slider>` then my filtering is not working based on my slider moving/selection, I hope this time it also should show the range values(at starting and ending places of slider bar, but it's not happening ?, here we are adding: `ng-model="itemrange.maxvalue"`)

[Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/mavdhana/ck0dotnt/1/) is available.

html:

```
<body ng-controller='PriceCtrl'>
    <slider floor="0" ceiling="50" ng-model-low="lower_price_bound" ng-model-high="upper_price_bound" ng-model="itemrange.maxvalue"></slider>
    lower_price_bound: <strong>{{lower_price_bound}}</strong>
    &nbsp;
    upper_price_bound: <strong>{{upper_price_bound}}</strong>
    <hr>
    <table border="1">
      <thead>
        <th>Name</th>
        <th>Min Price</th>
        <th>Max Price</th>
      </thead>
      <tbody>
        <tr ng-repeat='item in items|filter:priceRange'>
          <td>{{item.name}}</td>
          <td>{{item['min-acceptable-price']}}</td>
          <td>{{item['max-acceptable-price']}}</td>
        </tr>
      </tbody>
    </table>

  </body>
```

app.js:

```
var app = angular.module('prices', ['uiSlider']);

app.controller('PriceCtrl', function ($scope){

    $scope.itemrange = {
    maxvalue: 50
  };

  $scope.items = [{name: "item 1", "min-acceptable-price": "10",
                  "max-acceptable-price": "50"},
                  {name: "item 2", "min-acceptable-price": "5",
                  "max-acceptable-price": "40"},
                  {name: "item 3", "min-acceptable-price": "15",
                  "max-acceptable-price": "30"}];

  $scope.lower_price_bound = 0;
  $scope.upper_price_bound = 50;

  $scope.priceRange = function(item) {
    return (parseInt(item['min-acceptable-price']) >= $scope.lower_price_bound && parseInt(item['max-acceptable-price']) <= $scope.upper_price_bound);
  };
});
```

Please let me know where and what I am doing wrong ? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By using the "ng-model" parameter you are overriding the previous two model parameters.

For selection of a range, you only need the "ng-model-low" and "ng-model-high" parameters.

If you want to show the currently selected values above the sliders, that will require some custom CSS [(possibly similar to this)](https://css-tricks.com/value-bubbles-for-range-inputs/)

For a "quick and easy" solution, [use something like angularjs-slider.](https://github.com/angular-slider/angularjs-slider)

Comment: thanks for your reply, then how can I display those minimum/maximum values on top of my slider ? Could I know please ?

Comment: Just edited that into my answer. You'll need to use some custom HTML and  CSS to style your sliders to display those values - to my knowledge it doesn't form part of the default style.


The example I've provided is just a first-google-result link, and uses JQuery, but it should give you the general idea of what you need to do.

Comment: I don't want to display any selected values above the slider, I just need to display my low and high vales on top of slider, like: http://plnkr.co/edit/jOk6GmUdzOu99xJqQ0wU?p=preview

Comment: I have added sample image for min and max values on top of slider in the question description now, please check it once. Thanks in advance.

Comment: The plnkr you've linked is using a custom library, found [here](https://github.com/prajwalkman/angular-slider). Unfortunately it's now deprecated, but there are alternatives, [including this one, which is where your screenshot in the question comes from](https://github.com/angular-slider/angularjs-slider).

Comment: yes, they have used <rzslider/> module(rzslider), but I am using normal <slider> of angularjs, so is there any chance to develop using this ? or should I use rzslider only ?

Comment: The quickest way to go would be to use the angularjs-slider library that I linked above, save yourself the trouble. Otherwise it's the custom CSS route.

Comment: ok, sure, thanks a lot for your help !! I will check it out now.

Comment: Don't forget to mark the answer! (Provided it was actually the answer you were after of course)